# Good design of a Java equals method

Tags: java

I've seen this:

```
// Returns whether o refers to a Point object with  
// the same (x, y) coordinates as this Point object 
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Point) {
        Point other = (Point) o;
        return x == other.x && y == other.y;
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Why isn't it more sensible (and simpler) to require that the parameter of the equals method take a `Point` object. Then, if we try to compare a Point with a non-Point then the compiler will catch it. Isn't that better?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Answer (score 4):

Because then it won't override [`Object.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), which is the method used by many standard library algorithms for checking equality of two objects.

Many of these algorithms can operate on objects of different types, which makes it necessary that `equals` can compare your object to one of any other class.

Answer (score 1):

Because that break the first rule of the **overriding** and become an **overload** of the `equals()` method of the `Object` class

**Rules for method overriding:**

- **The argument list should be exactly the same as that of the
  overridden method.**
- The return type should be the same or a subtype of the return type
  declared in the original overridden method in the superclass.
- The access level cannot be more restrictive than the overridden
  method's access level. For example: if the superclass method is
  declared public then the overridding method in the sub class cannot
  be either private or protected.
- Instance methods can be overridden only if they are inherited by the
  subclass.
- A method declared final cannot be overridden.
- A method declared static cannot be overridden but can be re-declared.
- If a method cannot be inherited, then it cannot be overridden.
- A subclass within the same package as the instance's superclass can
  override any superclass method that is not declared private or final.
- A subclass in a different package can only override the non-final
  methods declared public or protected.

Comment: good points. Is this another version of the Liskov Substitution principle? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Answer (score -1):

You can simple use EqualsBuilder class in the Apache Commons library.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) { return false; }
    if (obj == this) { return true; }
    if (obj.getClass() != getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    MyClass rhs = (MyClass) obj;
    return new EqualsBuilder()
                  .appendSuper(super.equals(obj))
                  .append(field1, rhs.field1)
                  .append(field2, rhs.field2)
                  .append(field3, rhs.field3)
                  .isEquals();
}
```

would be

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);
}
```